# Auto scroll to bottom on addition of elements to FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I have searched and there seems to be many solutions for auto scrolling but either I don't understand the solution or it doesn't seem to apply directly to my situation. Let me explain. I have a simple control that looks like

Where the 'Document' property and its single Paragraph is defined on the view model as

```
private Paragraph _paragraph = new();
public Paragraph Paragraph
{
    get => _paragraph;
    set
    {
        _paragraph = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private FlowDocument _document = new();
public FlowDocument Document
{
    get => _document;
    set
    {
        _document = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

These two properties are initialized in the view model constructor

```
    Document = new FlowDocument();
    Paragraph = new Paragraph();
    Document.Blocks.Add(Paragraph);
```

Then 'lines' are added to the single paragraph like

```
    var run = new Run(line);
    Paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
    Paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Document));
```

Eventually the number of lines on the paragraph exceed the viewable area and the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` kicks in an allows the user to scroll to see the text. The problem I am facing is I would like this to automatically scroll to the line that was just added (the bottom of the document). I have tried `run.BringInToView()` and `Paragraph.BringInToView()`, but neither seems to affect scrolling. I know when faced with a similar problem with `TextBox` scrolling I had to attach a specific behavior so that the default was scroll to bottom rather than no scroll or scroll to top. I am not sure if I have to do something similar with `FlowDocumentScrollView` or not. From what I have searched it seems a big problem is that `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` doesn't have a `ScrollViewer` property so something like `ScrollToEnd` could be used. But this would put me at a disadvantage since the updates to the `FlowDocument` are happening in the view model and I don't have access to the associated `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. How can I automatically scroll to the bottom when a new element is added to the bottom of the `FlowDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access the ScrollViewer in the FlowDocumentScrollViewer like this

```
FlowDocumentScrollViewer docViewer = ...

var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)docViewer.Template
    .FindName("PART_ContentHost", docViewer);

scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
```

Comment: Using MVVM how do I get an instance of the FlowDocumentScrollViewer?

Comment: Scrolling is not done in a view model, but in the view. You would do this in the view whenever the Document changes. The view model might however expose a dedicated event to trigger the view.

Comment: Sorry to be so naïve. But is there an event or something that is in the view where this code should reside?

Comment: Also I need to name the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`?

Comment: Something like this? 

`<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="ProvisionStatusMonitor" Document="{Binding Document}" SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated"/>`

and

`        private void OnSourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
        {
            FlowDocumentScrollViewer docViewer = (FlowDocumentScrollViewer) sender;

            var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)docViewer.Template
                .FindName("ProvisionStatusMonitor", docViewer);

            scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
        }`

Comment: I can't tell, since I don't know your view, especially not how it is updated when you add content to an existing FlowDocument in the view model. `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Document))` will not do that.

Comment: The view is just this one line containing the FlowDocumentScrollView as shown above. So given this view where should the code you suggested be?

Comment: As said, in an event handler to an event that is fired by the view model when the document was modified. You would have to define such an event. This is out of the scope of your question, which was *how to do it*, not where exactly in some hypothetical code that you aren't showing

Comment: If the view calls `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Document))` whenever the document changes, the view may manually attach an event handler like `viewModel.PropertyChanged += ...`, where it could react on the event.